# Process is not exiting ffmpeg.exe only for the command which detects the silences from a video

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

The job of the method `ExecuteCommandSync` is to detect the silences from a video and return the output as string but when I run this code it never bring the value of `proc.HasExited` as `true`. If I forcefully drag the debugger to the line

```
result =proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

then it never exit the `ffmpeg.exe` so as a result control never returns back.

Although the same method is working fine for a different command like creating an audio file from a video. In this case `proc.HasExited` also returns false but it also generates the audio file successfully.

```
public static string ExecuteCommandSync(string fileName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        string workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        try
        {
            string command = string.Format("ffmpeg -i {0} -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f null -", "\"" + fileName + "\"");                
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

            procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;                
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;                
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();                
            proc.WaitForExit(timeoutMilliseconds);
            // Get the output into a string 
            if (proc.HasExited)
            {
                if (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                }
                else if (!proc.StandardError.EndOfStream)
                {
                    result = "Error:: " + proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

So please advice.

Comment: Why do you `WaitForExit` twice?

Comment: I have removed one, It was left there when I was sanitizing my code otherwise in my real code it is commented.